# How can I force my printer to print in black when it can't recognize 2 colour cartridges?

Tags: printing, printer, ink, cartridge

So I currently have this issue where my Epson WF-3620DWF can't find the blue and yellow cartridges. (They are official epson ones) and I have a full black cartridge in there. How do I force my printer to ONLY print in black and ignore the cartridge(s) not recognised error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Step 1**   Close any applications from which you print. Click the Windows Start button to open the Start menu, then click “Devices and
>   Printers” in the right column.
>
> **Step 2**   Click to select the color printer you want to configure to print in black and white. Right-click the selected color printer,
>   then click “Printing Preferences” in the context menu.
>
> **Step 3**   Click the “Color” tab in the Printing Preferences window and select the “Print in grayscale” option. Select the “High quality”
>   setting in the drop-down list below the “Print in grayscale” option.
>   Click the “Apply” button, then click “OK.”
>
> **Step 4**   Close the "Devices and Printers" window. Open Microsoft Word or another program from which you want to print color documents
>   in black and white. Open a file that contains a color image. Click
>   “File” and “Print,” then click “OK” or “Print” in the Print dialog
>   box.

[source](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/configure-color-printer-default-black-white-47987.html)

---

There is also a trick to ignore the warning message:

> Disabling the EPSON Status Monitor is the only way to stop annoying
>   warning messages due to using third-party ink cartridges including the
>   non-genuine ink warning message.
>
> - Select 'START'
> - Select 'Control Panel'
> - Select 'Printer and Faxes'
> - 'Right' Click on your printer icon Select 'Printer Preferences'
> - Find the box that reads 'Speed and Progress'
>
> Epson maintenance screen
>
> - Click in the empty box next to 'Disable Epson Status Monitor' A tick    will appear in the box
> - tick disable Epson monitor
> - Select 'Save'

[source](http://www.inkcloners.com/shopping_information/tips.php)

Comment: @DavidPostill - updated

Comment: Great - perfect ;)

Comment: This warning also appears on my printer too, does this disable stop it from appearing on the printer too?

Comment: @Mrfunny744 - I am not sure, honestly I don't think so. You should try it anyway and give a feedback if it works.

Comment: On windows 10 with a WF-7610 none of these options are available under devices and printers in the control panel.